# Field 'id' expected a number but got [<django.db.models.sql.query.Query object at 0x000002CFD4506EC8>]

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am building a BlogApp and I am trying to exclude posts with another model field.
BUT when i go to browser then this error is keep showing

> Field 'id' expected a number but got [<django.db.models.sql.query.Query object at 0x000002CFD4506EC8>].

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_owner = models.ForeignKey(User,default='',null=True,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=500,default='')
    tags = TaggableManager()

class AddFav(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='parent_user')
    favourite_users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='favourite_users', blank=True)
    blocked_tags = TaggableManager()
```

views.py

```
def posts(request):
    block_or_not = AddFav.objects.filter(favourite_users=request.user)

    exclude_this_list = []

    for excluding in block_or_not:
        exclude_this = excluding.blocked_tags.all()
        exclude_this_list.append(exclude_this)

    posts = Post.objects.filter(date_added__lte=now).exclude(tags=exclude_this_list)
```

I have no idea what is wrong in this.

Any help would be much Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not *append* the items to the list, but *extend* the list with all the elements in the `QuerySet`, so:

```
for excluding in block_or_not:
    exclude_this = excluding.blocked_tags.all()
    exclude_this_list += exclude_this

posts = Post.objects.filter(date_added__lte=now).exclude(
    tags__in=exclude_this_list
)
```

You can however probably exclude these with a single exclude statement:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(date_added__lte=now).exclude(
    tags__addfav__favorite_users=request.user
)
```

this will exclude a `Post` if there is a tag for which there is an `AddFav` object that has the `request.user` as (one of the) `favorite_users`.

Comment: Sir, Which method will be fast ? First or second ?

Comment: @refri: the second will only make *one* query, so it is likely more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this piece of code:

```
for excluding in block_or_not:
    exclude_this = excluding.blocked_tags.all()
    exclude_this_list.append(exclude_this)
```

`.all()` will return a queryset and then we are appending that queryset into another list. So at the end, `exclude_this_list` is a list of querysets which is not what we want.

Instead of appending the queryset, we can collect all the blocked tag ids and use `extend` because we need a flattened list.

```
for excluding in block_or_not:
    exclude_this = list(excluding.blocked_tags.values_list('id', flat=True))
    exclude_this_list.extend(exclude_this)
```